# Fastest way to import data from Postgres into SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: postgresql, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, etl

I am staging various kinds of data for reporting using SSIS.  The source is Postgres, the destination is SQL Server 2008 R2.  We use Windows unicode 32-bit drivers to connect to Postgres via system DSNs (%WINDIR%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe).  I am using Data Transformation tasks with ADO.NET and/or OLEDB objects to move data around (I've tried several combinations).

Most queries are just `SELECT * FROM tbl_postgres` and return no more than 1M records of varying type, mostly `VARCHAR(10) - (100)`, `int`, and a couple of large note columns.

Postgres server performance is ok.  The problem appears to be on the SQL Server side. It takes relatively short time to pull any amount of data from Postgres, but once SSIS gets into the "Execute phase is beginning" mode, I get 2k records per second tops from any table unless it's very small.

Sometimes, record count won't be moving at all (e.g. SSIS still says "Execute phase is beginning"), but then it adds another 3k records and sits still for another 10 minutes.  Eventually, SSIS tasks either straight up die and time out, or go red and "out of tuples".

Is there a way to optimize SSIS for fast data insertion from Postgres? My ultimate goal is to insert results of Postgres queries into SQL Server tables. Thanks.

Comment: `out of tuples` is an error you're receiving? That said, what if you change one of your data flows to not pull in the "note" columns. Large Object Types may result in paging to disk. Also, it sounds like you're running this through Visual Studio. That ETL process is wrapped in a debugger which adds significant overhead to the throughput.

Comment: Should I run the package via some other method, like command line?

Comment: Reduce your problem to the smallest scope possible. If it works then, gradually add complexity until it breaks or you've completed the task.

Comment: Specific to your problem: reduce your package to 1 data flow that pulls data from one table and pushes to another. If there is a note field, exclude it from the column list in your SELECT query (and don't use the drop down table selector)